# Feeding selectlist from database

Tags: php, sql-server, database, selectlist

I am trying to fill a selectlist from my database. I only want the column 'blogID' to fill it, however i get 10 different selectlists, all saying "choose one". Im not really sure how to solve it.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$serverName = "localhost"; 
$uid = "*****";   
$pwd = "*****";  
$databaseName = "blog"; 

$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                            
"PWD"=>$pwd,                            
"Database"=>$databaseName); 
$con=sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($con)
{
} else {
die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$result = sqlsrv_query($con,"SELECT TOP 10 * FROM blog_posts ORDER BY blogID DESC");
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) 
{ 
?>
<select>
<option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
 <?php
foreach($row['blogID'] as $name) { ?>
  <option><?= $name['name'] ?></option>
 <?php
} ?>
</select> 

<?php } sqlsrv_close($con); ?>
```

what am i doing wrong? tried severeal different approaches but this is as close as i get..

Comment: You need to move your opening tag `<select>
<option selected="selected">Choose one</option>` to before your `while()` loop, and the closing tag `</select>` after your `while()` loop closes. Also, you don't need to loop over your `$row['blogID']` -> `foreach($row['blogID'] as $name)`. Just output it directly -> `<option><?= $row['blogID'] ?</option>`, as it is a value, not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move `<select>` tag and `choose one` option  outside of loop and there is no need of `foreach` loop. This is the correct way of your code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$serverName = "localhost"; 
$uid = "*****";   
$pwd = "*****";  
$databaseName = "blog"; 

$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                            
"PWD"=>$pwd,                            
"Database"=>$databaseName); 
$con=sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($con)
{
} else {
die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$result = sqlsrv_query($con,"SELECT TOP 10 * FROM blog_posts ORDER BY blogID DESC");
?>
<select>
<option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
<?php
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) 
{ 
?>
<option><?= $row['name'] ?></option>
<?php 
} 
?>
</select> 
<?php
sqlsrv_close($con); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using `<select>` inside your while loop.

Try this :

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $serverName = "localhost"; 
    $uid = "*****";   
    $pwd = "*****";  
    $databaseName = "blog"; 

    $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                            
    "PWD"=>$pwd,                            
    "Database"=>$databaseName); 
    $con=sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if ($con)
    {
    } else {
    die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    $result = sqlsrv_query($con,"SELECT TOP 10 * FROM blog_posts ORDER BY blogID DESC");
    ?>
    <select>
    <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
    <?php
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) 
    { 
    ?>
      <option><?= $row['blogID'] ?></option>
    <?php } 
    ?>
    </select> 
    <?php
    sqlsrv_close($con); ?>
```

**Please dont use short tags in PHP**

Comment: Also move the option - choose one outside of the loop

Comment: Thank you, one step closer, now i get 1 selectlist but all with the value "choose one"